# Where to ask about a english conversation or sentence online?

Tags: discussion

As an ESL learner without native English speakers around, it is difficult to know how to say native English conversation or sentences.

Usually, the conversation or sentence questions are in daily life and thus the questions could be very basic or easy for native speakers. I feel less confidence if they are proper to be asked here.

So, I am looking for a online forum or place to ask questions of English's conversation or sentence. Could you recommend some of such kinds of services? Thank you.

Comment: You could try the 'cousin' stack of this one, [ELL.se].

Comment: @JeffZeitlin I don't think that's appropriate. The OP here is asking if they can ask questions of the form "Here's a transcribed sentence or conversation. Is it OK?" or "Here's a situation. What is a good way to say that in English". Both are considered pretty off topic as is in either ELU or ELL. I wish there were a place for those kinds of questions, but I don't think SE is right for it.

Comment: @Mitch - I read it as asking if _translations_, not _transcriptions_, are correct, and the querent specifically placed the context as being an English learner. If that sort of question is not acceptable in ELL, I'm not sure how useful the stack would be at all.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin I'm not an expert in what's on or off topic at ELL, it's just my expectation of ELL.

Comment: i also think that ELL would be the appropriate venue.

Comment: @Jeff Zeitlin ELL does not have a 'resources' tag (I took the trouble to check). There are many good questions on ELL; the name is almost a misnomer, as the site was set up to consider more basic questions than would be expected on a site aimed at linguists – questions from Anglophones as well as non-native speakers. But there are reasonable constraints, as here, if not identical ones. // I'd suggest trying 'Language Learning SE'.

Comment: Questions about English, no matter how minor, are welcome in the chat rooms of ELU and ELL, although people may take a while to respond

Comment: Thank you all for kindly answering this question. EEL is a good idea. Thank you all again.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin Not just google-translation kind's "translation" but more like the "context", "usage", "mind-set" or "culture". There is too much different from Chinese and English. As an ESL learner, it is always an goal there - to think like an native English speaker. EEL is a better place for the goal. Thank you for your reply and advice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [English Language Learners](http:////ell.stackexchange.com) site can probably help with many of your questions. If you have questions that don't fit in with the main site, you can always ask in either [EL&U's chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95/di-kmprhnsb-rum) or come join us in [ELL's main chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24938/language-overflow).

This is from the [What topics can I ask about here?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for ELL:

> English Language Learners Stack Exchange is for  people who are
>   learning or teaching English as a foreign language.
>
> The best questions are [those that have specific answers](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers); ELL is not a general discussion forum.
>   In general, ask here if you have a question which covers:
>
> - Word choice, usage, and meaning
> - Grammar
> - Dialect differences
> - Spelling and punctuation
> - Pronunciation and accents
> - Other practical problems you encounter or face while learning English

Before posting, you may want to take a look at our ["Please, everyone… details. Please"](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/976/)  post on meta. It has a lot of good advice for writing questions that will be well received by the community. [One of the answers](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4584/) has links to examples of different types of questions that have appropriate detail.